# Dynamic Buttons Android

Tags: button, dynamic

I have shown on a 10-key layout dynamically created, now I need to retrieve the ID of the button pressed to release the necessary procedure. Here the code.

```
Button Btn;
Toast msg;
RelativeLayout rl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    Btn = (Button) findViewById( R.id.Btntu );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Btn = new Button(this);
        Btn.setText("Número: " + i);
        Btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Btn.setId(i);

        rl = new RelativeLayout(this);  

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Btn.setLayoutParams(parametros);

        rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(                        
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                            );

        rl.addView(Btn);
        ll.addView(rl);
    }
```

I need the function to retrieve the ID of the button pressed.
Thank you all.
:o)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getId()` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Btn = new Button(this);
        Btn.setText("Número: " + i);
        Btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Btn.setId(i);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("Button", "ID clicked: " + Btn.getId());
                // Or even
                Log.d("View", "ID clicked: " + v.getId());
            } 
        });
        (...)
}
```